# XML reading using Perl

Tags: perl, xml-parsing

I am new to the Perl language. I have an XML like,

```xml
<xml>
   <date>
       <date1>2012-10-22</date1>
       <date2>2012-10-23</date2>
   </date>
</xml>
```

I want to parse this XML file & store it in array. How to do this using perl script?

Comment: I want output as @array = qw(2012-10-22 2012-10-23)

Comment: http://learn.perl.org/faq/ leads to https://metacpan.org/module/Task::Kensho which leads to https://metacpan.org/module/Task::Kensho#XML-Development:-Task::Kensho::XML which has some suggestions.

Comment: http://learn.perl.org/faq/ also leads to http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq6.html which leads to http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq6.html#How-do-I-match-XML-HTML-or-other-nasty-ugly-things-with-a-regex-

Answer (score 3):

```
Use XML::Simple - Easy API to maintain XML (esp config files) or 
see XML::Twig - A perl module for processing huge XML documents in tree mode.
```

Example like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

my $xml = q~<xml>
   <date>
       <date1>2012-10-22</date1>
       <date2>2012-10-23</date2>
   </date>
</xml>~;

print $xml,$/;

my $data = XMLin($xml);

print Dumper( $data );

my @dates;
foreach my $attributes (keys %{$data->{date}}){
  push(@dates, $data->{date}{$attributes})
}

print Dumper(\@dates);
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '2012-10-23',
          '2012-10-22'
        ];
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::XSH2;

xsh << '__XSH__';
  open 2.xml ;
  for $t in /xml/date/* { 
      my $s = string($t) ;
      perl { push @l, $s }
  }
__XSH__

no warnings qw(once);
print join(' ', @XML::XSH2::Map::l), ".\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way with [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => 'data.xml');
my @nodes = $doc->findnodes('/xml/date/*');
my @dates = map { $_->textContent } @nodes;
```

Answer (score -2):

If you can't/don't want to use any CPAN mod:

```
my @hits= $xml=~/<date\d+>(.+?)<\/date\d+>/
```

This should give you all the dates in the `@hits` array.

If the XML isn't as simple as your example, using a XML parser is recommended, the `XML::Parser` is one of them.

Comment: never use regex for parsing xml

Comment: well that's assuming you CAN use another tool, but I've found myself working in very old servers where I could not use them, so if the XML is simple enough using a regex is not pretty but works.

Comment: If you can run Perl code that you write, you can use a Pure Perl XML library.